# Parsec, access last user state after parsing has ended

Tags: haskell, parsec

I have a simple parser `scriptParser`, which uses a user state (type and content not important here). It returns either a `String` for an error message or a list of `Statement` (again, not important how this is defined):

```
parseScript :: String -> Either String [Statement]
parseScript input
  = let parsed = runParser scriptParser initialUserState "" input
    in  case parsed of
          Left e   -> Left (parseError input e)
          Right ss -> Right ss
```

`parseError` simply formats the error message based on `e` and `input` (it shows the snippet of code around the error position).

My question is, what if I'd like to customize the error message also based on the last available user state? Clearly the user state is gone after `runParser` has ended. Would `runParserT` allow to access the user state afterwards?

Comment: I worry that the question is semantically ill-formed. If my parser is `(put 3 >> fail "") <|> (put 4 >> fail "")`, which state is "last"? More generally, in case of errors, which of the many states that led to failing branches should be considered the "last available" one, and why?

Comment: Thanks @DanielWagner. By "last" I meant the one before a failure, wherever this might occur. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but because the internal Parsec state is backtracking, I expect this to make sense.

Comment: I expect under normal circumstances that because of backtracking there will be *many* failures, each with a potentially different "final" state. It's not clear that any one of those failures is "special" enough to warrant its state being called *the* final state. Reporting all final states might be semantically sensible, but could be a serious memory leak in the case of successful parses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand, Parsec throws away the built-in user state on errors, so there's no way to recover it.

Alternatively, you can transfer the user state into the `m` monad in `ParsecT s u m a`, so for instance you might have `ParsecT String () (State s) a`.

That way, `runParserT` returns in type `State s (Either ParseError a)`, from which you can recover the last state.

Also, since `ParsecT String () (State s) a` has a `MonadState s` [instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec.html#t:ParsecT), you can use `get` and the other `MonadState` functions without issue.

Comment: Right. One big advantage of the internal state is that it is back-tracking, which I had hoped to keep.

Comment: I could perhaps achieve this by using both states. Use the internal state as I'm doing now, but mirror it into the global state after every update. Ugly, very ugly. But perhaps the only option if I want to both a back-tracking state and access it from outside the parser?

Comment: I'm not sure that works out. Even if you mirror on update, you don't mirror the rollbacks on backtracking.

Comment: Another option could be using [`parsers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsers) and/or [`trifecta`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/trifecta-1.5.2/docs/Text-Trifecta.html), which lets you push your parser *inside* a `StateT` (and you can parse with parsing instances lifted over `StateT`) which preserves backtracking. I'm not sure though whether that always throws away state on error like Parsec.

Comment: Right, or [megaparsec](https://github.com/mrkkrp/megaparsec) which has the same feature and is a fork of Parsec - to maximize compatibility of existing code.

Comment: After a bit more thought, that doesn't work either (discards state on error too). I think what you need is a primitive implementation of errors that remembers the last user state...